# React-Redux - Getting errors on dispatch - TypeError

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatch

In my authActions files, I'm getting a `unhandled rejection (typeerror) cannot read property of data of undefined`

Pointing to this line of code

`dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));`

I have that same block of code defined in a request body and it's not pointing to that error, just this one. Not sure what is going on.

**authActions.js**

```
export const loadUser = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    // User loading
    dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING });


    // Fetch user
    axios.get('/api/auth/user', tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res => dispatch({
      type: USER_LOADED,
      payload: res.data
    }))
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, 
      err.response.status));
      dispatch({
        type: AUTH_ERROR
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: could you log err and check if it contains data

Comment: right below that line right?

Comment: you are directly setting res to payload you will have to get the `res.json()` which returns a promise after that you will have to set the data in next `.then` callback

Comment: @mph85, you can comment the dispatch call and log it or log it above the dispatch call

Comment: ok sorry for both, im not sure how to go about doing that, this is my first time using react/redux

Comment: i put the console.log(err) above that line but how do i check it?

Comment: take a look at the browser console to see what got logged

Comment: Ok actually put a console.log(err.response) and a console.log(err.response.data) right above the dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.data)); and returned undefined for the first and uncaught (in promise) cannot read property of undefined

Answer (score 0):

> unhandled rejection (typeerror) cannot read property of data of undefined

The error message is saying that there are no data called response on error, so its undefined, which means u can not get data on undefined. Try to log the error or debug your code to check what is really in error and then evolve reject handler base on true shape of error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code and see what console logs in developer console by clicking F12.
I understand that you are not well versed with React/Redux so providing with code to debug.

```
export const loadUser = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    // User loading
    dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING });


    // Fetch user
    axios.get('/api/auth/user', tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res => {
      if (res.data) {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED,
            payload: res.data
        })
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response)
        console.log(err.response.data)
        if (err.response.data) {
          dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
          dispatch({
            type: AUTH_ERROR
          });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Ok actually put a `console.log(err.response) and a `console.log(err.response.data) right above the `dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.data)); and returned `undefined for the first and `uncaught (in promise) cannot read property of undefined`

Comment: i tried your code and in the `console.log(err.response.data)`, it responded with that same `uncaught (in promise)` error

Comment: This essentially means your error object doesn't have correct data. Please look into the error object returned. It could be an issue with auth/user api, it should return correct error object.

Comment: is there any way to screenshot the errors that are popping up?